# symfony2 and godaddy route returns 404 response

Tags: symfony, routes

I have uploaded to my godaddy webhost this cotroller in my symfony

```
    <?php
    namespace AppBundle\Controller;

    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

    class DefaultController extends Controller {

            /**
             * @Route("/contact")
             */
            public function contactAction(Request $request) {
                    /* my contact action */
            }

            /**
             * @Route("/", name="homepage")
             */
            public function indexAction(Request $request) {
                    /* my index action */
            }

    }
```

the problem is with my contact action. when I go to www.myserver.net/contact it returns 404 response, but it loads normally the index action. What do I do wrong?

Comment: How do you import your routes?

Comment: What's the output of `php app/console debug:router`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `app/config/routing.yml` contains this:

```yaml
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```